# How to set data (in ReactJs frontend using useState) ,coming from multiple collections (as a one response) in MongoDb database?

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, react-hooks, use-state

Schemas and the controller I am using are available here [code snippets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801264/how-to-fetch-data-from-multiple-collections-in-mongodb)

Comment: Sorry, this question isn't quite a duplicate, but what have you tried as far as any frontend code goes? Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have a state `[data, setData] = useState(null)`

and when you call GET request from backend

```
fetch('http://<your endpoint>')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data=>{
    setData(data.data)
}
```

and then you can just use the data from the state `data` like
`data.employees`
`data.profQuali`
`data.accQuali`
as you wish

ps. Storing all type of data in the single state is not a good practice, you should separate it into different state as well as the backend side, they are too mixed, however, you could learn that more while you develop your app, good luck! ^_^